# gcm invalid registration error

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

i pass to the server a nickname and then i get registration id by nickname from my database.

GOOGLE_API_KEY is a server key generated by google gcm api.

this is the php code of the server:

```
<?php

require_once("db_config.php");


$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or      
die(mysqli_error());

$db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error()) or die(mysqli_error());


$nicknames = $_POST['nicknames'];
$message = $_POST['message'];




$registration_ids = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT regId FROM Users WHERE nickname = '$nicknames'");
$numOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($registration_ids);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($registration_ids );
printf ("%s\n",$row["regId"]);


if($numOfRows > 0) {

$url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
//$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array('registration_ids' => array($registration_ids), 'data' => array("message" => $message),);
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY, 'Content-Type: application/json');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
else {
    echo 'false';
}     

?>
```

after i send the message, i recieve:

{"multicast_id":4772095405461687926,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}]

i also printed to my self the registartion id that i get from my database and it is matched to the device`s registration id.

ty for your help.

Answer (score 1):

ok i resolved my problem.
the problem was that in this line "array($registration_ids)", the $registration_ids is a result object, so i changed it to $row["regId"] and than i got the registration id.

now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the registration token that you are passing to the server. See [Downstream message error response codes](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

You may also look at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey) which suggests to check the validity of the registration token.

Comment: as i said, i checked and the registration id of my device matches the registration id i send to gcm server.

Comment: Documentation-wise, these are the suggested solution. Please check again if there is a possible space somewhere. Good luck!